# Ajuda para slider jQuery

Tags: jquery

Para essa missão, estou sem ideias.

Para sliders mais elaborados uso o Slider Revolution e mais básicos, o Wow Slider, sempre mesclando com o PHP.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    slideWidth: 600
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bxslider">
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee1.jpg" title="Funky roots"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee2.jpg" title="The long and winding road"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee3.jpg" title="Happy trees"></div>
</div>
```

Na imagem é possível visualizar o que acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Do lado direito tem alguns tópicos.

Eu preciso fazer um slider que, ao invés de clicar no bullet mude, que mude ao clicar em algum dos tópicos.

Comment: Coloque o seu código

Comment: Eu já fiz com o Wow Slider e o Slider Revolution. Ambos não permitem mudar o bullet. Só se muda de slider por lá ou pelas setas.

Comment: Estou usando este código: https://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions/ É como se o bullet fosse os tópicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue com o WOW Slider estilizando as *bullets* nativas do plugin de acordo com o estilo que você usa nos links do seu menu de tópicos e em seguida movendo a `div` `class="ws_bullets"` para dentro da `div` onde fica o menu.

O WOW Slider possui a seguinte `div` onde ficam as *bullets*:

```
<div class="ws_bullets">
   <a href="#" title="Link 1"><span>1</span></a>
   <a href="#" title="Link 2"><span>2</span></a>
</div>
```

Você pode aplicar os estilos do seu CSS aos `<a>` dessa `div` selecionando-os no CSS:

```
.ws_bullets a{
   ESTILOS
}
```

Em seguida, mova a `div` `class="ws_bullets"` para a `div` do menu:

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
   $(".ws_bullets").prependTo("#teste");
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(window).on("load",function(){
   $(".ws_bullets").prependTo("#menu"); // Substitua "#menu" pelo id do seu menu
});
```

```css
.ws_bullets a{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="wowslider-container1" style="float: left;">
   <div class="ws_images">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="http://wowslider.com"><img src="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/data1/images/41ijsgfvwzl._sx355_.jpg" alt="jquery slider" title="41IJsgFvWzL._SX355_" id="wows1_0"/></a></li>
         <li><img src="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/data1/images/220pxbasketball.jpg" alt="220px-Basketball" title="220px-Basketball" id="wows1_1"/></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="ws_bullets">
      <a href="#" title=""><span>Link 1</span></a>
      <a href="#" title="220px-Basketball"><span>Link 2</span></a>
   </div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/engine1/script.js"></script>
<div id="menu" style="display: block; width: 300px; float: left; background: #ddd; padding: 15px;"></div>
```